# Page Transition Greensock

Tags: javascript, css

estoy hace rato trabajando con greensock y no puedo deducir como lograr ciertas page transition que realiazan paginas como esta https://www.lagenceversions.fr/projets , cuando vas al menu o cuando decidis cambiar del home al contact y realiza esa transición, si alguien me da una mano con algun codigo o snippet seria de muchisima ayuda, gracias

Comment: Es probable que utilicen alguna libreria o plugin de javasript para esas transiciones, o pueden haberlo construido ellos mismos. Tendrías revisar el código de la página para saberlo.